# failing to set user destination address from auto predicted places in google maps

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, google-geolocation

flutter throwing unhandled exception error when trying to set user destination point on ridesharing flutter app

**CODE**

```
class PlacePrediction extends StatefulWidget {

  final PredictedPlaces? predictedPlaces;
  PlacePrediction({
    this.predictedPlaces
});

  @override
  State<PlacePrediction> createState() => _PlacePredictionState();
}

class _PlacePredictionState extends State<PlacePrediction> {

 getPlaceDirectionDetails(String? placeId, context) async{
   showDialog(
       context: context,
       builder: (BuildContext context)=>ProgressDialog(
         message: "Setting up Drop-Off. Please wait....",

       )
   );

   String placeDirectionDetailUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/places/details/json?place_id=$placeId&key=$mapKey";
   var responseApi = await RequestAssistant.receiveRequest(placeDirectionDetailUrl);

   Navigator.pop(context);
   if(responseApi == "error occured. Failed. no response."){
     return;
   }
   if(responseApi["status"] == "OK"){
     Directions directions = Directions();
     directions.locationName = responseApi["result"]["name"];
     directions.locationId = placeId;
     directions.locationLatitude = responseApi["result"]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
     directions.locationLongitude = responseApi["result"]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"];

     Provider.of<AppInfo>(context, listen: false).updateDropOffLocationAddress(directions);

     setState(() {
       userDropOffAddress = directions.locationName!;
     });
     
     Navigator.pop(context,"obtainedDropoff");

   }

 }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: (){
          getPlaceDirectionDetails(widget.predictedPlaces!.place_id, context);

        },
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              const Icon(
                Icons.add_location,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),

              SizedBox(width: 10,),
              Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        widget.predictedPlaces!.main_text!,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.green[400],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        widget.predictedPlaces!.secondary_text!,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.green[400],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

**Error**
E/flutter (15529): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
E/flutter (15529): #0      _PlacePredictionState.getPlaceDirectionDetails (package:dride/widgets/place_prediction_type.dart:42:18)
E/flutter (15529): 
E/flutter (15529):

error coming from this part

```
 if(responseApi["status"] == "OK"){...}
```

watched several tutorial videos on YouTube but getting the same solution that is not working on my app

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or you can push a sample app into your github repo that we can clone and test in our end.